# Get data from both tables what join should I use

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

I have T1 as table 1

```
----------------
field1 | field2
---------------
 val1  | val2
```

I have T2 as table 2

```
----------------
field1 | field2
---------------
 val11  | val22
```

I want to write a query which can produce result like this

```
 field1 | field2 | T1.T2 | 
 ------------------------|
 val11  | val22  | T2    | 
 val1   | val2   | T1    |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, you can use a CTE or SubQuery then `ORDER BY [T1.T2] DESC` as

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Col1, Col2, 'T1' [T1.T2]
  FROM T1
  UNION
  SELECT Col1, Col2, 'T2'
  FROM T2
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY [T1.T2] DESC;
```

**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=66b718ec3fa7b52f9fdf1d9da2acb772)**

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this query is useful... I used union to join the 2 tables.

```
mysql> select field1 ,field2 from T2 union select field1, field2 from T1;
```

Comment: There is no MySQL tag there.